# Delta overwrite - specific partitions

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, delta-lake, delta

I need to read the data in CSV from source partitioned by year, month, data and hour. Just need to write the data as it is to target in delta format with same year, month, data and hour partition.

Hourly partition data in the source contains only specific hour, with no overlapping. Hence, planning to read specific hour data and write to delta in overwrite mode.

```
# read specific hour partition, df already contains year,month,day,hour column
df = spark.read.option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").csv(source_path) 

# create delta table if not already exists

DeltaTable.createIfNotExists(spark) \
    .tableName(f"{schema_name}.{table_name}") \
    .location(target_path) \
    .addColumns(df.schema) \
    .partitionedBy(partition_columns) \
    .execute()

# write as delta

df.write.mode("overwrite") \
    .saveAsTable(f".{schema_name}.{table_name}")
```

Also tried replaceWhere:

```
# is this the right way to use values for replaceWhere?

df.write.mode("overwrite") \
    .option("replaceWhere", "year = year AND month = month AND day = day AND hour = hour") \
    .saveAsTable(f"{catalog_name}.{schema_name}.{table_name}")
```

In both the approaches of write using overwrite, previous data is overwritten. i.e. when I look at the delta_log content, only latest file has action 'add', all older files has action 'remove'.

**Question**:  How do we write data as delta to specific partition in overwrite mode?

Comment: Add this spark conf before writing:
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode","dynamic")

Comment: thanks Abdennacer. Just a while ago added   .option("partitionOverwriteMode", "dynamic") and it worked. Just curious what is the difference between replaceWhere vs Dynamic Partition? At high level, both seem to overwrite only specific partitions?